# CMSEditableRegion inside a code loop

Tags: c#, .net, content-management-system, kentico

I am trying to add a cmseditableregion to my Kentico webpart that exists inside of tabbed content, now the amount of tabs are flexible so I would like to generate this dynamically. I have tried the method that follows (stringbuilder) but it just renders it as html and not as a control when passed to a literal.

```
for (int i = 1; i <= TabCount; i++)
        {
            sb.AppendLine("<li class=\"htab-list__item--fininfo active\">");
            sb.AppendLine("<a href=\"#financial-result\" class=\"htab-list__link tab-link\">");
            sb.AppendLine("<cms:CMSEditableRegion runat=\"server\" id=\"ttl" + i.ToString() + "\" RegionType=\"Textbox\" RegionTitle=\"" + i.ToString() + " Title\" />");
            sb.AppendLine("</li>");
```

Is there a way to make the CMSEditableRegion be able to be set dynamically in the code so that when the loop builds the page code it will be in the right spot as a control and not just html.

The full code has more html and 3 editable regions per loop but it wont even work with just one.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Adding control dynamically is done as follows:

```
// Let's assume that 'plc' is a placeholder. But it can be any control.
plc.Controls.Add(new LiteralControl("<li class=\"htab-list__item--fininfo active\">"));
plc.Controls.Add(new LiteralControl("<a href=\"#financial-result\" class=\"htab-list__link tab-link\">"));
plc.Controls.Add(new CMSEditableRegion { ID = "someid", RegionType = CMSEditableRegionTypeEnum.TextBox, RegionTitle = "sometitle" });
plc.Controls.Add(new LiteralControl("</li>"));
```

Also check out [MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/kyt0fzt1).

Comment: Thanks, this is exactly what I was looking for, working as expected!

Answer (score 1):

I suggest you to create an ad hoc PageType (called DocumentType in Kentico 7) where you can put the HTML text needed. Then you can display it using a Repeater web part or a ASP.NET repeater if, like me, you prefer to work in code.

Comment: Would this be in the CMS or could I create and store it all in the pageinfo (like the Editor currently does) I would like to avoid needing a subitem for each page that has a Tab in the CMS.

Comment: Using the way I suggested you have to put the data in the CMS outside the page. You can try the solution proposed by rocky, maybe it's better for you.

Comment: I'd be willing to guess @Meredori is using ASPX mode vs. Portal because this can easily be done using a page type and adding a repeater to your template.